# Screen scraping through nokogiri or hpricot

Tags: ruby, xpath, screen-scraping, nokogiri, hpricot

I'm trying to get actual value of given xpath. I am having the following code in sample.rb file

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.changebadtogood.com/'))
desc "Trying to get the value of given xapth"
task :sample do
  begin
    doc.xpath('//*[@id="view_more"]').each do |link|
      puts link.content
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "error" 
  end
end
```

Output is:

> **View more issues ..**

When I try to get the value for other a different XPath, such as:
`/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/h1/span`
then I get the **"error"** message.

I tried in this in Nokogiri. I don't know why this is giving result for few XPaths only.

I tried the same in Hpricot.
http://hpricot.com/demonstrations

I paste my url and XPaths and I see the result for
**`//*[@id="view_more"]`**
as
**View more issues ..**
[This text is present at bottom of recent issues header]

But it is not showing result for:
**`/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/h1/span`**
For this XPath I'm expecting the result `Bad`.
[This was present in 
http://www.changebadtogood.com/ as the first header of class="hero-unit" div.]

Comment: There's a lot of problems here. You didn't include the code that's raising an error. What good does catching an error and printing 'error' do? Let the error get raised so you can debug it. And you should fix your indenting before posting a question.

Comment: And, you have asked 14 questions and not yet accepted a single answer. I've answered your question below, but I urge you to revisit [your previously-asked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/792302/vinothini) and for each find the one answer that best answered your question (if any) and Accept it (click the checkmark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has to do with a poor XPath selector, and is unrelated to Nokogiri or Hpricot. Let's investigate:

```ruby
irb:01:0> require 'nokogiri'; require 'open-uri'
#=> true
irb:02:0> doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.changebadtogood.com/')); nil
#=> nil
irb:03:0> doc.xpath('//*[@id="view_more"]').each{ |link| puts link.content }
View more issues ..
#=> 0
irb:04:0> doc.at('#view_more').text  # Simpler version of the above.
#=> "View more issues .."
irb:05:0> doc.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/h1/span')
#=> []
irb:06:0> doc.xpath('/html/body/div[4]')
#=> []
irb:07:0> doc.xpath('/html/body/div').length
#=> 2
```

From this we can see that there are only two divs that are children of the `<body>` element, and so `div[4]` fails to select one.

It appears that you're trying to select the span here:

```html
<h1 class="landing_page_title">
  Change <span style='color: #808080;'>Bad</span> To Good
</h1>
```

Instead of relying on the fragile markup leading up to this (indexing anonymous hierarchies of element), use the semantic structure of the document to your advantage for a selector that is both simpler and more robust. Using either CSS or XPath syntax:

```ruby
irb:08:0> doc.at('h1.landing_page_title > span').text
#=> "Bad"
irb:09:0> doc.at_xpath('//h1[@class="landing_page_title"]/span').text
#=> "Bad"
```