# Other than Nokogiri / hpricot gem available? for Screen scraping

Tags: xpath, screen-scraping, rails-3.1

I tried Nokogiri and hpricot to find the value of xpath. But that's not working how i m expecting (I described my problem in [Screen scraping through nokogiri or hpricot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793506/screen-scraping-through-nokogiri-or-hpricot)). Anyone knows other gems for screen scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other popular web scraping libraries for ruby:

- [scRUBYt](http://scrubyt.rubyforge.org/files/README.html)
- [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/)
- [Watir](http://watir.com/)